# How to collect all the objects from $cacheFactory

Tags: angularjs

I was planning to use $cacheFactory to cache my objects at client side to solve

1. Performance
2. Multiple view to access the same object

General use case is

Client can request a device through cache service. If it is available in $cacheFactory return it. If it is not available, fetch it from the server and add it to $cacheFactory and return it. Everything looks nice.

Another use case is

Client can request all devices. How to return all the devices cached in $cacheFactory.

I didn't see any method which gives key value pairs similar to Java Map.Entry. Can some one please point if there is any way to iterate $cacheFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look example of `$cacheFactory` in [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory), they did what you want there...

```
angular.module('cacheExampleApp', []).
  controller('CacheController', ['$scope', '$cacheFactory', function($scope, $cacheFactory) {
    $scope.keys = [];
    $scope.cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');
    $scope.put = function(key, value) {
      if ($scope.cache.get(key) === undefined) {
        $scope.keys.push(key);
      }
      $scope.cache.put(key, value === undefined ? null : value);
    };
  }]);
```

in this controller it pushes key into an array if it is valid and after that in html just traverse through keys array like this...

```
<p ng-if="keys.length">Cached Values</p>
  <div ng-repeat="key in keys">
    <span ng-bind="key"></span>
    <span>: </span>
    <b ng-bind="cache.get(key)"></b>
  </div>
```

Comment: But we are maintaining one more copy of keys. Is there any other way without maintaining key set?

Comment: do you plan to use two $cacheFactory?

Comment: Yes. I have different types of objects and want to use different caches which give the flexibility of clearing the cache for specific object type

Comment: you can create as many as $cacheFactory you want... just create service each of them and use them in controller according to your logic... this solution is for showing how to reach all element in your $cacheFactory as you asked...